# How to get provider specific ConnectionString from Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ado.net, connection-string

using ado.net tipically we need to define a connectionstring to create a sqlconnection object, and if we use the entity framework, we have to dedine a connectionstring too.

is threre any way to get the specific provider connectionstring used by entity framework?

Assuming that originally on ado.net we define the CS like:

```
"Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
```

and Entityframework should translate their CS format on something like that, is it possible to obtain this?

what i pretend is to know if is possible to get the specific provider connectionstring generated by EF?

How can i convert a entityframework connectionstring on a sqlserver connectionstring?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
string entityConnectionString = ...

var builder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(entityConnectionString);
string providerConnectionString = builder.ProviderConnectionString;
```

Comment: You just saved me hours of headaches.  +100 internets to you, my good sir!

Comment: How do we go the other way?

Comment: @PeterX, what do you mean? You want to get the EF connection string from the provider connection string? Just create a new instance of `EntityConnectionStringBuilder`, set the `ProviderConnectionString`, `Provider` and `Metadata` properties, and get the `ConnectionString` property.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque The thing is... What do you set `Metadata` to?

Comment: @Zero3 you just leave it alone. It's already populated if you created the `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` from an existing connection string.

Answer (score 4):

**Found the solution:**

```
            System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection c = (System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection)EFDBcontext.Connection;
            String S = c.StoreConnection.ConnectionString;
```